# Is there any departure tax to pay at the airport when leaving Thailand?

Tags: air-travel, thailand, fees-and-charges, bkk

I know that usually departure tax is included in flight tickets, but not always.

A guy in my hostel here in Bangkok says he has had to pay at the airport in both Vietnam and Indonesia. I once had to pay an unexpected "airport improvement tax" at the airport when leaving Canada, which amounted to the same thing even though it wasn't officially a "departure tax".

So when taking an international flight out of Thailand is there a departure tax or any other tax or fee which must be paid at the airport?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Bangkok's airport website](http://www.airportsuvarnabhumi.com/about-suvarnabhumi-airport/bangkok-international-airport-departure-tax/):

> Suvarnabhumi International Airport Departure Tax (Bangkok
>   International Airport Departure Tax) = 700 Baht

BUT, note that it also says:

> Since February 1, 2007 the 700 Baht international departure tax was
>   included in the price of flight tickets.
>
> (The international departure tax is usually included in the cost of
>   your ticket. However, some travel agency may exclude the tax from
>   their published rate, so please review the terms & conditions of the
>   ticket price carefully every time before making a purchase . )

Comment: Cool. Hopefully this means there are no other last-minute fees to pay either.